# How to Insert multiple panels in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I am making a small GUI which requires at least 4 panels to be added in JFrame. I am using GridBagLayout. Each of these panels have some labels and text Areas of different length.
I inserted 3 frames as :

```
    jf.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    jf.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jf.add(panel4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Here jf is the Frame. Now I have one more Panel (Panel3), which has to come between panel2 and panel 4. Please give me some ideas how do we insert more than 3 panels.
thank you

Comment: You should probably have a look at [this guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), to help you choose a layout that suits your needs. From what I can understand, you want to display the panels vertically. For that end, `BoxLayout` may be of help.

Answer (score 2):

Change the layout of the content pane of the frame to something other than BorderLayout, and add the panels where you want. You should probably use a GridLayout of 1 column and 4 rows. Since you master the GridBagLayout for all your panels, you could also use a GridBagLayout for the content pane if you prefer.

Comment: Either that, or maybe a BoxLayout on the page axis.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you are using the **BorderLayout** and not the **GridBagLayout**. Actually it's very easy to use just think your Frame is a Excell Page when using the GridBagLayout. I wrote a [full and very useful guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360000/best-guide-for-learning-how-to-use-gridbaglayout) for beginners and experts too about how to use properly the GridBagLayout.

Here's the code:

```
package prueba;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BlocPrueb extends JFrame{

JPanel container;   
JPanel panel1;
JPanel panel2;
JPanel panel3;
JPanel panel4;

GridBagLayout cockatoo;
GridBagConstraints c;

  public BlocPrueb(){

      JButton g = new JButton("JPanel1");
      JButton h = new JButton("JPanel2");
      JButton j = new JButton("JPanel3");
      JButton k = new JButton("JPanel4");

      cockatoo = new GridBagLayout();
      c = new GridBagConstraints();

      container = new JPanel();
      container.setLayout(cockatoo);

      panel1 = new JPanel();
      panel2 = new JPanel();
      panel3 = new JPanel();
      panel4 = new JPanel();


      //Will use BorderLayout in the panels, cause its a demostration but it works as well as if it was the only panel in the JFrame.
      panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      panel1.add(g);

      panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      panel2.add(h);

      panel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      panel3.add(j);

      panel4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      panel4.add(k);

      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 0;
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      container.add(panel1, c);

      c.gridx = 1;
      c.gridy = 0;
      container.add(panel2, c);

      c.gridx = 2;
      c.gridy = 0;
      container.add(panel3, c);

      c.gridx = 3;
      c.gridy = 0;
      container.add(panel4, c);

      getContentPane().add(container);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setTitle("Cockatoo Panels inside a JFrame (GridBagLayout)");
      pack();
      setResizable(true);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setVisible(true);

  } 

    public static void main (String args[]){

        BlocPrueb v = new BlocPrueb();

}


}
```

And here's what you should get:
[image: JPanels using GridBagLayout]

Comment: @Antorio, where is the link for  full and very useful guide? The one you provided in your answer is broken.